# How to update the correct state value in a parent component that gets its value from a child component using hooks in react?

Tags: reactjs, state, react-hooks

I am working on a react project and have an issue with the using current correct state value.  I've recreated the issue in a small dummy project that contains a Parent component and a Child Component. The Child is passed down props from the Parent component, one state variable and one function that updates said state utilizing react hooks (useState).  Within the original function residing in the Parent component is a call to a second function that performs an action based on the current state.  I have the console logs and result showing that the passed down function sends back up the correct value to update, but the following function does not use the updated value, instead seems to always be one render behind.

I've attempted using async/await as well as the useEffect hook.  I've been able to get the "expected" result using some variation of useEffect in this small dummy project however it didn't translate into the actual project duo to their being more function calls that also depend on a state value, although I may just be misunderstanding/ doing something wrong.

```js
export const Parent = () => {

    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    const [fruit, setFruit] = useState(null);

    const counter = (index) => {
        console.log("index passed in: ", index);
        setCount(index);
        secondMethod()
    }

    const secondMethod = () => {
        console.log('state of count in second method', count);
        const arr = ['apple', 'cherry', 'orange', 'kiwi', 'berry'];
        setFruit(arr[count]);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <p>Hello from Parent, current count: {count}</p>
            <Child counter={counter} count={count}/>
            <p>result of second method: {fruit}</p>
        </div>
    );
}

export const Child = ({ counter, count }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>Child comp</p>
            <button onClick={() => counter(count + 1)}>
                Click on send counter
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The console log value on index is correct as well as the { count } output.  The result of the console log from the secondMethod and therefore the state of the setFruit is incorrect and uses the state from one render behind?  So count will be displayed as 1 but the secondMethod will still have count as value 0 so displays "apple" instead of "cherry".  I appreciate any and all help/suggestions, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React state updates action are asynchronous and are batched for performance gains. There's no guarantee that `console.log('state of count in second method', count);` will reflect the updated state.

**Solution 1:** use the `index` value in `secondMethod` passed in as a parameter

**Solution 2:** update the `fruit` **after** `count` was updated, with the `useEffect` hook. Replace `secondMethod` with:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('state of count in useEffect', count);
    const arr = ['apple', 'cherry', 'orange', 'kiwi', 'berry'];
    setFruit(arr[count]);
}, [count, setFruit]);
```

**Solution 3:** If your states depend heavily on each other, then maybe they should be part of the same single state. That way you can use the function version of setState, that always receives the correct previous value.

```
// join separate states together
const [fruitCount, setFruitCount] = useState({ count: 0, fruit: null });

const counter = index => {
    setFruitCount({ count: index });
    secondMethod();
};

const secondMethod = () => {
    const arr = ["apple", "cherry", "orange", "kiwi", "berry"];
    // use setState function, count is taken from the previous state value
    setFruitCount(prevState => ({ ...prevState, fruit: arr[prevState.count] }));
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I figured useEffect needed to be incorporated.  Would it still be the same solution if there were multiple other functions (ie thirdmethod(), fourthmethod(), etc...) that also depended on the state value but interacted with it differently?

Comment: Yes, use one of the mentioned solutions (I've added one more), to avoid multiple setState calls that depend on each other in the same render cycle. Solution 1 works because it does not depend on the other setState function. Solution 2 works because useEffect is executed in the next render. Solution 3 works because the function version of setState receives the correct previous state value.